# Reference to resources ID inside variables Terraform without using modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to reference resources ID inside variables Terraform without using modules.
I'm trying to create a full stack from VPC AND Ec2. every resources in individual files named EC2.tf and vpc.tf
I want to reference subnets ids and security group IDs in terraform.tfvars

```
subnet_id = [ "${aws_subent.primary_private_subnets.id}" ,"${aws_subent.secondary_private_subnets.id}" ]
vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${aws_security_group.sgs[0].id}","${aws_security_group.sgs[1].id}" ]
```

I get that error:

```
Error: Variables not allowed

on terraform.tfvars line 80:
80: vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${aws_security_group.sgs[0].id}","${aws_security_group.sgs[1].id}" ]
Variables may not be used here.
```

variables.tf

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  type = any
  default = "" 
}

variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  type = list(any)
  default = [  ]
}

variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {
  type = list(any)
  default = [  ]
}
```

Comment: If these are within the same module then they should be directly referenced and not re-assigned as input variables. If these are within a different module then they need to be declared as outputs. Are the resources in the same or different module?

Comment: In the same module but I try to do that to make the code more reusable.

Comment: Also, to Matthew's point, it's impossible to assign values to variables after the fact. They need to be known **before** applying the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify root module input variables using techniques such as a `.tfvars` file, the `.tfvars` file is essentially "outside of the module" in the same sense that a `module` block is "outside of" the module it's calling.

References in your `.tfvars` file are therefore impossible because there is nothing else in scope outside of the root module for those expression to refer to.

If you want to write your root module in such a way that it makes us of different objects depending on the input variables then you can achieve that by defining input variables that *indirectly* specify which set of references to use, and then define those references inside the module.

Here's an example that achieves that using only a single input variable:

```
variable "network_config" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  network_configs = tomap({
    example1 = {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
      subnet_ids = toset([
        aws_subnet.primary_private_subnets.id,
        aws_subnet.secondary_private_subnets.id,
      ])
      security_group_ids = toset(
        aws_security_group.sgs[*].id,
      ),
    }
    example2 = {
      vpc_id             = aws_vpc.vpc.id
      subnet_ids         = toset([])
      security_group_ids = toset([])
    }
  })
  network_config = local.network_configs[var.network_config]
}
```

With the above configuration you'd set `network_config` to either `"example1"` or `"example2"` depending on which is more appropriate for the given situation, and then `local.network_config` inside the module will refer to whichever of the two network configs matches that key. For example, `local.network_config.vpc_id` would give the appropriate VPC ID to use based on the caller's network config selection.

I used just a single lookup key here to keep the example relatively straightforward, but you can use a more complex strategy with more input variables or with more complex input variables if you like, as long as you can describe in the `locals` block how to translate the input variable values into the values you will actually use.

The crucial detail here is that the root module is creating an abstraction where the caller refers only *indirectly* to the objects inside. In this case I did that by having the caller choose from a fixed set of "network configuration names", with the module encapsulating exactly how each of those configurations is really implemented.